# How to start a block of code after a certain time?

Tags: arduino-uno, time, millis

I'm using a ATMega328P-PU on a breadboard as an arduino. How do you start a code after say 20 seconds have elapsed since startup?
Example code:-

```
if(condition)
{
     //Start sending morse code!
}
```

My current code uses `millis()` and fails miserably. The speaker does not get activated. I'm using the standard circuit mentioned at the [Arduino website](http://arduino.cc/en/main/standalone)
My current code:-

```
time = millis();
  if(time>=20000)
      txEnable=true;
      val = analogRead(analogPin);
  if(val!=0)
  {
    standby=false;

  }
  else
  standby=true;
  if(txEnable==true && standby==true)
 {

  if(!callsignSender->continueSending())
    {
        callsignSender->startSending();
    }

 }
```

Comment: You are comparing an analog reading with zero. Are you sure you don't mean `digitalRead()`? If you really need an analog value, instead of comparing with zero you should compare to some low threshold.

Comment: I'm basically writing this code for a ham wireless repeater. Its in Pune.(VU2PHA). The analog read value is for detecting any incoming signal for repeating. Its a small scale model for the same big repeater. The repeater custodian is my friend and I'm making it for him.

Comment: The define a "noise threshold" and treat any value below the threshold as equivalent to zero.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet I'm going to fine tune that once I get in touch with VU2ASH (one of the custodian). I'm making a protosketch.

Comment: I have to use the following protocol. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-MHXkswdqyO2CX3Q_D83SsUi4Uosm34mRVtucOoSkCM/edit?usp=docslist_api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following bare-minimum code will switch pin 13 to high after 20 seconds:

```
void setup() {                
  // assuming pin 13 has a LED connected (as on most Arduino boards)
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(13, LOW); // would also work without this line
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long time = millis();
  if (time >= 20000) {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // set the LED on
  }
}
```

Try if this works for you, i.e. if a LED connected to that pin will light up 20 seconds after reboot.

If not you will need to find the problem: Is your ATmega running at the correct speed? Is your code executed at all? Are the peripherals working?

Comment: `millis()` returns time in unsigned long format. Above code needs to be adjusted. (Otherwise its bound to create trouble) I'll try your code though. Pls try searching for alternatives!

Comment: Well, it would work for what it's written. But I've changed it to `ulong`.

Comment: Note that I don't suggest that you actually use code written like that for any other purpose than testing...